# Regex search in page http and https

Tags: php, regex, http, https

I have this php code:

```
 $cinemagiaprepare=file_get_contents("http://www.bing.com/search?q=$numele+$anul+site:https://www.cinemagia.ro/filme/&format=rss&count=1");
$cinepatern='#<\/title><link>(https:\/\/www.cinemagia.ro.+?)<\/link><description>#';
if (preg_match($cinepatern, $cinemagiaprepare, $matchc))
$numeletv1=($matchc[1]);
```

Thats code search in :`http://www.bing.com/search?q=Walk%20of%20Fame%202017%20site:https://www.cinemagia.ro/filme/&format=rss&count=1`

for this link `http://www.cinemagia.ro/filme/world-premiere-2009x00-1650809`

My code only search `https`. I want to search for `https` and `http`.

I try this regex:

```
$cinepatern='#<\/title><link>(https.*:\/\/www.cinemagia.ro.+?)<\/link>
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/oNeMMb/1 this regex select all code.

Comment: The `/` doesn't need to be escaped unless it is being used as a delimiter. Urls can also be protocol independent. You'd be best off using a parser and pulling the `link` element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the optional `s` in https, it would be this

`'#</title><link>(https?://www\.cinemagia\.ro.+?)</link><description>#'`

Answer (score 0):

With simpleXML:

```
$sxe = simplexml_load_file('http://www.bing.com/search?q=$numele+$anul+site:https://www.cinemagia.ro/filme/&format=rss&count=1');

echo $sxe->xpath('//link[starts-with(., "http://www.cinemagia.ro") or starts-with(., "https://www.cinemagia.ro")]')[0];
```